# rsyslog has no /var/lib/rsyslog directory, which results in: "Permission denied', path: '/imjournal.state.tmp"

Tags: centos, rsyslog

Host details:

```
kkahn@host:~$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
kkahn@host:~$ uname -a
Linux host.example.com 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 22 21:09:27 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
kkahn@host:~$ ps aux | grep -i rsyslog
root       8199  0.0  0.0 224604 11456 ?        Ssl  Jun25   0:02 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n


kkahn@host:~$ sudo systemctl status rsyslog.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
* rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-06-25 23:30:55 EDT; 9h ago
     Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
           http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
 Main PID: 8199 (rsyslogd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
           `-8199 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n

Jun 26 08:34:40 host.example.com rsyslogd[8199]: fopen() failed: 'Permission denied', path: '/imjournal.state.tmp'  [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jun 26 08:35:01 host.example.com rsyslogd[8199]: fopen() failed: 'Permission denied', path: '/imjournal.state.tmp'  [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jun 26 08:36:01 host.example.com rsyslogd[8199]: fopen() failed: 'Permission denied', path: '/imjournal.state.tmp'  [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jun 26 08:37:01 host.example.com rsyslogd[8199]: fopen() failed: 'Permission denied', path: '/imjournal.state.tmp'  [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jun 26 08:37:40 host.example.com rsyslogd[8199]: fopen() failed: 'Permission denied', path: '/imjournal.state.tmp'  [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
```

It's less permission denied, and more so the fact that the directory `/var/lib/rsyslog` (where `imjournal.state.tmp` would live) does not exist:

```
kkahn@host:~$ sudo ls -latr /var/lib/ | grep -i rsyslog
kkahn@host:~$
```

I have several other hosts of the same OS however they all have `/var/lib/rsyslog/` and therefore `/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp`. I'm not seeing anything anamolous with the config file either, here's an `m5sum` comparison to a server that has `/var/lib/rsyslog/`:

**Bad server**:

```
kkahn@host:~$ md5sum /etc/rsyslog.conf 
0dd94a0c285fb32f41fa5b226e83c26b  /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

**Good server**:

```
kkahn@host:~$ md5sum /etc/rsyslog.conf 
0dd94a0c285fb32f41fa5b226e83c26b  /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

The directive that would be responsible for this is in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` even uncommented on the host:

```
# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
```

I'm unable to find a way to tell if `rsyslog` has been properly configured/installed; I don't know how to "true up" this installation to make sure it's not broken in some way. I don't think simply creating the directory is safe to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A properly installed *rsyslog* package has `/var/lib/rsyslog` part of the package:

```
# rpm -qf /var/lib/rsyslog
rsyslog-8.24.0-52.el7_8.2.x86_64
```

So if the directory is missing, that's an anomaly and there's no reason *rsyslog* will attempt to create it, since in CentOS it's expecting it to be present, as part of the package. There was probably in the past an human error leading to the removal of this directory, which led to *rsyslog* failing the next time it was restarted (eg: reboot), rather than immediately after.

You can either create it manually as root:

```
# mkdir -m 700 /var/lib/rsyslog
```

or if you don't trust how it would have to be created, reinstall the package:

```
# yum reinstall rsyslog
```

Then simply start it:

```
# systemctl start rsyslog
```